# jenkins Permission hints to mysql: command not found？

Tags: sql, linux, bash, jenkins

jenkins version is 1.165.3

My goal is to pass Jenkins Job Execute shell run :

```
mysql -f -h 127.0.0.1  -uroot -p${pwd}  <<EOF
create database if not exists ${name};
use ${name};
source ${file_name_sql};
EOF
```

result :

```
[workspace] $ /bin/bash +x /tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 3: date: command not found
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 3: cut: command not found
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 8: mysql: command not found
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 16: date: command not found
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 16: cut: command not found
/tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh: line 17: -: syntax error: operand expected 
(error token is "-")
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: `date`?, `cut`? Add complete /tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem through the root user running Jenkins.

But what you mentioned /tmp/hudson2881472966362898766.sh, I can't find this file under the system directory